# How to align text widget in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to align two text widgets so they are side by side instead of being below but I cannot find any method that does this.

```
from Tkinter import *
win = Tk()
win.geometry('800x500')
win.configure()

textbox1 = Text(win, height=10, width=10)
textbox2 = Text(win, height=10, width=10)

textbox1.pack(pady=25)
textbox2.pack(pady=25)

textbox1.configure(borderwidth=0)
textbox2.configure( borderwidth=0)

mainloop()
```

Comment: have you read the documentation on the `pack` method? It has arguments that let you specify a side (top, bottom, left, right).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `side=LEFT` and `padx`:

```
textbox1.pack(side=LEFT,padx=10)
textbox2.pack(side=LEFT,padx=10)
```

Or you can use the `grid` geometry manager:

```
textbox1.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=10)
textbox2.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=10)
```